# Association rule mining using support count

Tags: data-mining

what if i have 0.3 as support count for 5 item transactions?.
How to use whether it is 0.3*5/100 or any other methods to be followed?.

I don't know please anyone.

Comment: I have trouble understanding.  Please explain in more detail.

Comment: explain your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is no mathematical solution to this - it's up to whoever specified 0.3 to be *precise*.

Interpreting this as 0.3*5/100 would be very unusual. Why would you do so?

For fractional values less than 1, the usual interpretation would be relative frequency: 0.3 * N when you have N transactions.
For positive integers, you would interpret it as absolute frequency.